# How to show a "Loading..." gif image above the Splash image in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, ios, splash-screen

I want to show a GIF image over the splash-screen while the app is loading its data.

I have splash image that is showing for at least about 3 or 4 seconds which is why I want to show loading text, like a gif image, over the splash image so that users think that app is loading.

Comment: The HIG explicitly says that you 1) should not use the **launch image** as a splash and 2) should launch as fast as possible. You can show a loader once the app has started but don't try to show the launch image after the app has launched. That is just bad, even if you are loading data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add one label to your splash image and an `NSTimer` which change it's text periodically just as below

```
splash = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.frame];
splash.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"splash"];
[self.window addSubview:splash];
```

this is the code i use to show my splash screen and then

```
NSTimer *loading = [[NSTimer alloc]init];
[loading performSelector:@selector(YOUR_SELECTOR) withObject:YOUR_LABEL afterDelay:0.3f];
```

where `YOUR_SELECTOR` is method in which you set the label text and `YOUR_LABEL` is label for which you set the text

**EDIT**
sorry for `NSTimer` actually i used activityindicator with text loading...
in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method

the code for it is

```
splash = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.frame];
splash.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"splash"];    
[self.window addSubview:splash];
hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc]initWithView:splash];
[splash addSubview:hud];
hud.labelText = @"Loading...";
[hud show:YES];
[self performSelector:@selector(Load_FirstView) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

and `Load_FirstView` method is as follow

```
-(void)Load_FirstView
{
    [splash removeFromSuperview];
    MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    masterViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Comment: This assumes the window is visible, the OP has not specified when the data is being loaded, I suspect that it's done before showing the main view, otherwise the splash would not be visible for the entire duration.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Default.png as a splash image, then there is no way to animate that. One way would be to launch the app quicker, only to then show an animated view for the duration of loading the data. So basically your only solution would be to move away from Default.png and use a custom view instead that can be animated.

Comment: I m using Default.png and I have to show loading... gif image as an activity indicator in iphone.

Comment: That's my point though, if at the moment you have Default.png visible for the entire time, then there is no way of animating that.

Comment: I don't want to animate it. I just want to show a label over splash image while it is showing.

Comment: If that label is static then simply add it to the image with a image editor.

Answer (score 0):

Start off by using the Default.png and then load a `UIView` that contains a single `UIImageView` with the same frame as the `UIView` (entire screen). Set the Default.png as the `UIImage` of the ImageView and add whatever controls (such as the `UIActivityIndicatorView`) as you need.